# what is wrong with this stream pipeline in a loop using util.promisify and async/await

Tags: node.js, async-await, nodejs-stream

I have a array of image urls. I try to load them in a loop, resize them and save to file system.
First I had the problem, that request is just implementing the stream interface, but I can not use it directly in the pipeline like this: ***await pipeline(request, imgstream, writableStream)*** - solved this by combining request with pipe.

Here is the code:

```
async function processImage(url) {
    try {
      const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);
      const resizeTransform = sharp()
        .resize(160, 105);
      const imgstream = request(url).pipe(resizeTransform);
      const localFile = getLocalUrl(url);
      const writableStream = fs.createWriteStream(localFile);
      await pipeline(imgstream, writableStream);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
}

urlArr.forEach(processImage);
```

If I run this with 100 images, it works fine for 30... 50 images, but the remaining images have a filesize of 0 bytes, and the console prints this:
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:162:27)

I'm currently on a win 10 computer.
What may be wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your code is wrong. You are calling `urlArr.forEach(processImage);` as `processImage` is an **asynchronous** function, the default implementation of `forEach` does not `await` the callback passed as the parameter. You need something like this to `await` the function:

```
for(let i=0; i< urlArr.length; i++){
  await processImage(urlArr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Oh, of course, how could I be so blind. Thank you for the advice. But I have to wrap the for loop also in an async function to be able to use it with await.